# Access violation reading location 0xfdfdfdf1

Tags: c++

```
//Where is my problem?

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cassert>
using namespace std;
enum cls{ bb, bc };
const int max = 10;

class Ship
{
private:
    char*name;
    cls clas;
    int numGuns;

public:
    Ship(char* =" ", cls=bb, int=0);
    Ship(const Ship &);
    ~Ship();
    Ship& operator=(Ship &);

    char*getName()const;
    cls getClas()const;
    int getNumGuns()const;
    void print()const;

};


Ship::Ship(char*n, cls c, int num)
{
    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    assert(name != NULL);
    strcpy(name, n);
    clas = c;
    numGuns = num;
}

Ship::Ship(const Ship & s)
{
    name = new char[strlen(s.name) + 1];
    assert(name != NULL);
    strcpy(name, s.name);
    clas = s.clas;
    numGuns = s.numGuns;
}

Ship::~Ship()
{
    delete[]name;
}

Ship& Ship::operator=(Ship & sh)
{
    if (this != & sh)
    {
        delete[]name;
        name = new char[strlen(sh.name) + 1];
        assert(name != NULL);
        strcpy(name, sh.name);
        clas = sh.clas;
        numGuns = sh.numGuns;
    }
    return*this;
}

char* Ship::getName()const
{
    return name;
}

cls Ship::getClas()const
{
    return clas;
}

int Ship::getNumGuns()const
{
    return numGuns;
}

void Ship::print()const
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl << "Clas: " << clas << endl << "numGuns:" << numGuns << endl;
}


class Navy
{
private:
    char* country;
    int size;
    Ship*arr;
public:
    Navy(char* =" ", int=0);
    Navy(const Navy&);
    ~Navy();
    Navy& operator=(const Navy&);
    void addShip(Ship);
    void printNavy()const;
};


Navy::Navy(char* c, int s)
{
    country = new char[strlen(c) + 1];
    assert(country != NULL);
    strcpy(country, c);

    size = s;

    arr = new Ship[s];
    assert(arr != NULL);
}


Navy::Navy(const Navy& n)
{
    country = new char[strlen(n.country) + 1];
    assert(country != NULL);
    strcpy(country, n.country);

    size = n.size;

    arr = new Ship[n.size];
    assert(arr != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < n.size; i++)
        arr[i] = n.arr[i];
}

Navy::~Navy()
{
    delete[]country;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        delete[]arr;
    }

}


Navy& Navy::operator=(const Navy& n)
{

    if (this != &n)
    {
        delete[]country;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
           delete[]arr;
         }

        country = new char[strlen(n.country) + 1];
        assert(country != NULL);
        strcpy(country, n.country);

        size = n.size;

        arr = new Ship[n.size];
        assert(arr != NULL);
        for (int i = 0; i < n.size; i++)
            arr[i] = n.arr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}


void Navy::addShip(Ship s)
{
    arr[size] = s;//??
    size++;
}


void Navy::printNavy()const
{
    cout << "Country of Navy: " << country << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i].print();
    }
}


int main()
{
    Ship s1("A", bb, 10);
    s1.print();

    Ship s2("A1", bb, 11);


    Navy n("GR", 3);

    n.addShip(s1);

    n.addShip(s2);
    n.printNavy();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

That is one program that create navy, which have array of ship and country as private components. I think that this is very simple program but I cannot understend why it throw exception.I am new in c++, so I will be very happy if someone tell me where is the problem.

Comment: You should try to run a debugger like gdb.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: I guess void Navy::addShip(Ship s), it is marked with ??? comment

Comment: `char* =" "` should not compile, missing `const`.

Comment: Avoid `new`/`delete` and use `std::string` and `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Navy::addShip(Ship s)
{
    arr[size] = s;//??
    size++;
}
```

Here You run over the bounds of array (because size member initially equals the number of elements in array)! You should keep count of Your ships and dynamically reallocate the array!

I would suggest getting rid of dynamic memory allocation (`new`) and use `std::vector` for storing Your objects.

Comment: Thanks to all,but still trowing wxception and I think that problem is  here,but dont know why and how to fix it                                                    if (this != & sh)
    {
        delete[]name;
        name = new char[strlen(sh.name) + 1];
        assert(name != NULL);
        strcpy(name, sh.name);

Comment: You "THINK" or it really fails there? The problem with memory access exceptions is that they can happen anywhere in Your code if You overwrite some random memory (like in the addShip method). Comment out the addShip method contents and see if Your app crashes!

Comment: Thanks all.Fix it! :) :))